# Reference to listing environment label not showing up correctly

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, listings

in the code given below, I am trying to get the reference to the listing block to show up correctly, in this case, show up as "Code 1" instead of "Code code:test" as it is currently doing.  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\newcommand*{\mainColor}{myblueii}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\newcommand{\codeTitle}[2]{Code}
\newcommand{\codeTitleContent}{\hspace*{3mm}\begin{minipage}{.75cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
    {\sffamily\Large \codeTitle}
\end{minipage}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{
    \begin{mdframed}[
        linecolor=Gray,
        backgroundcolor=myblueii,
        skipabove=4mm,
        skipbelow=0mm,
        innertopmargin=2mm,
        innerbottommargin=0mm,
        innerleftmargin=0mm,
        innerrightmargin=10pt,
        leftmargin=0mm,
        rightline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linewidth=1mm
        ]
        \codeTitleContent
        \vspace*{-4mm}
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}

\lstset{
    style = {Matlab-editor},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Gray!80}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm, 
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblueii},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\color{\mainColor}{Code {#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{New Code}

\renewcommand{\codeTitle}{Matlab Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=RangeBearingSensor]
V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);
P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);
W = diag([0.1, 1*pi/180].^2);
map = LandmarkMap(20);
veh = Bicycle('covar', V);
veh.add_driver( RandomPath(map.dim) );
sensor = RangeBearingSensor(veh, map, 'covar', W, 'angle', [-pi/2 pi/2], 'range', 4, 'animate');
\end{lstlisting}\label{code:test}


How come the reference here \matref{code:test} does not show up correctly?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use a `\hyperref` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition

```
\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\color{\mainColor}{Code {#1}}}%
}
```

is unnecessarily complicated and logically wrong as well.

While `\hyperref[foo]{bar}` will make a link to the label `foo` displaying `bar` then, it will not display the reference behind the label.

The link should be done with `\ref` and a surrounding group around `\color{...} \ref{}` in order to prevent the leaking of the color change.

Another severe logical error: `\label` should not used after `lstlisting`, but as optional value `label=code:test` in `[...]`, otherwise the label grabs the `\@currentlabel` value of the last `\refstepcounter` command outside of the `lstlistings` environment, in this case the `\refstepcounter{section}`.

Another and better possibility: Use `cleveref` for a specialized listing environment that is applied for matlab codes only or apply `\crefname{listing}{code}{codes}` and `\Crefname{listing}{Code}{Codes}` for all listings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\newcommand*{\mainColor}{myblueii}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\newcommand{\codeTitle}[2]{Code}
\newcommand{\codeTitleContent}{\hspace*{3mm}\begin{minipage}{.75cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
    {\sffamily\Large \codeTitle}
\end{minipage}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{
    \begin{mdframed}[
        linecolor=Gray,
        backgroundcolor=myblueii,
        skipabove=4mm,
        skipbelow=0mm,
        innertopmargin=2mm,
        innerbottommargin=0mm,
        innerleftmargin=0mm,
        innerrightmargin=10pt,
        leftmargin=0mm,
        rightline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linewidth=1mm
        ]
        \codeTitleContent
        \vspace*{-4mm}
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}

\lstset{
    style = {Matlab-editor},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Gray!80}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm, 
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblueii},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
  %\hyperref[#1]{\color{\mainColor}{Code \ref*{#1}}}%
  {\color{\mainColor}{Code \ref{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{New Code}

\renewcommand{\codeTitle}{Matlab Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=RangeBearingSensor,label=code:test]
V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);
P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);
W = diag([0.1, 1*pi/180].^2);
map = LandmarkMap(20);
veh = Bicycle('covar', V);
veh.add_driver( RandomPath(map.dim) );
sensor = RangeBearingSensor(veh, map, 'covar', W, 'angle', [-pi/2 pi/2], 'range', 4, 'animate');
\end{lstlisting}


How come the reference here \matref{code:test} does not show up correctly?

\end{document}
```

[image]